# std::sort comparing elements to null

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11

I have the following sorting algorithm, which sorts an `std::vector` of unique `armor_set` pointers.  By some property of my sorting algorithm, it chokes up and runs into undefined behavior which ends up comparing a valid `lhs` to a `rhs` which is a `nullptr`.

Despite moving the algorithm around multiple times, I've been unable to discern the problem.  I feel as though I'm missing some sort of simple rule I should be following regarding how this `std::sort` algorithm works.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
std::vector<armor_set*> armor_sets;

//insertion of unique armor sets here

std::sort(armor_sets.begin(), armor_sets.end(), [](armor_set* lhs, armor_set* rhs)
{
    auto lhs_collectible_count = collectible_mgr::get().count(lhs->needed_collectible);
    auto rhs_collectible_count = collectible_mgr::get().count(rhs->needed_collectible);

    if(lhs_collectible_count > 0 && rhs_collectible_count == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(lhs_collectible_count == rhs_collectible_count)
    {
        return lhs->sort_index > rhs->sort_index;
    }
    else
    {
        auto lhs_collectibles_needed_count = lhs_collectible_count - lhs->collectibles_needed;
        auto rhs_collectibles_needed_count = rhs_collectible_count - rhs->collectibles_needed;

        return lhs_collectibles_needed_count > rhs_collectibles_needed_count;
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any `nullptr`s in the vector to begin with?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yep, double and triple checked.

Comment: can you show the definition of `armor_sets`

Comment: You should always check pointer args against nullPtr.

Comment: @Fendorio In therory yes, but there should be no need for it here since there are guaranteed (in other parts of the code) for there to not be `nullptr`s in the vector.

Comment: Why are you storing raw pointers in the first place? And what is `collectible_mgr::get()`?

Comment: The architecture of the program (which I've inherited) demands them to be raw pointers.  `collectible_mgr::get().count()` returns the amount of collectibles the player has where `needed_collectible` is a unique identifier for the collectible.

Comment: The comparison function must follow a strict-weak-ordering.  For example, If I am the sort function, I give you two armor_set pointers and you return a true/false value.  I then give you the same two armor_set pointers, but in the opposite order, and you return the same true/false value.  Guess what -- you lose.  That in a nutshell is a violation of the strict weak ordering.   There is no way a < b, and at the same time b < a.  Looking at your somewhat complex comparison function, my guess is that you're violating this rule.

Comment: BTW, For one compiler, Visual C++, this is how the debug runtime library checks for strict-weak-ordering violations during the calls to std::sort.  The comparison function is called twice, first with order A,B and then with order B,A and the results of each are compared.

Comment: I'll move my comment to the Answer.  I feel that this is where the problem arises.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The comparison function must follow a strict-weak-ordering.

For example, If I am the sort function, I give you two armor_set pointers, ask you "which one comes first?" and you return a true/false value denoting which value comes first. I then give you the same two armor_set pointers but this time, change the order of items.  I ask you the same question "which comes first?".  You then return the same true/false value. Guess what -- you lose.

That in a nutshell is a violation of the strict weak ordering. There is no way `a < b`, and at the same time `b < a`. Looking at your somewhat complex comparison function, my guess is that you're violating this rule.

If you're using Visual Studio, the debug runtime does this exact check for ordering violations like this.  The comparison function is called twice, the first time with A,B order, and the second time with B,A order.  The return values for each call are compared, and an assert() will occur if there is a violation.

Comment: a<b and a>b holds when a=b

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that.  The == check seems to burn a lot of programmers not familiar with how std::sort works.

Comment: @notbad Neither a<b nor a>b holds when a==b.

Comment: I think the particular problem here is that `a<b` implies `!(b<a)`. That breaks down because there's no matching `return false` for the `return true` case.

Comment: @Casey yes. I made a mistake. !(a<b) and !(b<a) holds when a=b.

Answer (score 2):

The Compare operation (lambada) is the problem. The operator in `sort` should make sure the defined order is strict weak order. i.e

```
1)For all x, it is not the case that x < x (irreflexivity).
2)For all x, y, if x < y then it is not the case that y < x (asymmetry).
3)For all x, y, and z, if x < y and y < z then x < z (transitivity).
4)For all x, y, and z, if x is incomparable with y, and y is incomparable with z, 
    then x is incomparable with z (transitivity of incomparability).
```

You function seems miss it. For example:

```
armor_set* lhs{
 lhs->needed_collectible=0;
 ....
}

armor_set* rhs{
 lhs->needed_collectible=1;
 ....
}
```

When you call `compare(lhr, rhs)`, it may return `true` or `false` depends on other value. While you call `compare(rhs, lhs)`, note the order is different, it will always return `true`. Both `compare(a,b)` and `compare(b,a)` return true is not allowed, which violates the property of strict weak order.

Comment: What about the current algorithm violates this rule?

Comment: @cmbasnett The order of the parameters in comparison function should not effect the comparison result unless they are equal.

Comment: std::sort doesn't require a total ordering, it requires a strict weak ordering.

Answer (score 1):

The specific failure is a missing

```
if(lhs_collectible_count == 0 && rhs_collectible_count > 0)
{
    return false ;
}
```

which should be the second or third test.