# Why is the std::map.find() not working in following case?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, key, equality, stdmap

The `snmp.h` header file contains the definition of `AsnObjectIdentifier` struct and unfortunately there is no equality operator overload for this struct. I want `AsnObjectIdentifier` to be the key of an `std::map` but the problem is that `find()` is not able to find the key in the map. I have defined a custom comparator `AsnObjectIdentifierComparator` which serves as third template argument to the std::map declaration. Minimum reproducible code for the scenario is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned int UINT;

typedef struct {
  UINT   idLength;
  UINT * ids;
} AsnObjectIdentifier;

struct AsnObjectIdentifierComparator {

  bool operator()(const AsnObjectIdentifier& left, const AsnObjectIdentifier& right) const {
    UINT* leftOidArr = left.ids, * rightOidArr = right.ids;
    UINT smallerOidLen = (left.idLength < right.idLength ? left.idLength : right.idLength);

    for (UINT i = 0; i < smallerOidLen; i++) {
      if (leftOidArr[i] < rightOidArr[i]) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    if (smallerOidLen == left.idLength) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

};


typedef std::map<AsnObjectIdentifier, std::string, AsnObjectIdentifierComparator> MibMap;


int main(void){

  MibMap map;

  UINT expectedOID1ids[] = { 1, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1 };
  AsnObjectIdentifier expectedOID1 = { 8, expectedOID1ids };

  map.insert( std::pair<AsnObjectIdentifier, std::string>(expectedOID1, "present") );

  cout << map.size() << endl;

  if(map.find(expectedOID1) == map.end()) {

      cout << "Not found"  << endl;   

  }

}
```

It makes sense that `AsnObjectIdentifierComparator` defines the order how the keys are placed in the map but of no use if we are not able to find the key at first place. There are no more template arguments in case of `std::map` and it does not have something like `keyequal` argument as in `unordered_map`. Moreover I don't have control over the definition of `AsnObjectIdentifier` as it is already defined in other header file. How can I work out of this scenario?

Comment: *but the problem is that find() is not able to find the key in the map* -- Just to let you know, your program doesn't even get as far as this when run using Visual C++, as an "invalid comparator" assertion is raised, thus confirming the answer given by @Jarod42.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that is what brought me here.

Comment: OK, so did you realize that the strict-weak-ordering was the error?  Your question didn't mention this, thus the impression that you didn't totally understand the reason for the error.

Comment: [See this for a quick explanation of how Visual Studio tests this scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842749/stdsort-comparing-elements-to-null/21843204#21843204)

Comment: I understand it properly now. The documentation pages for strict weak ordering make it so confusing to understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your comparison doesn't respect strict weak ordering.

I suggest to use helper from stl when you need to customize as [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) (with `std::tie`) or in your case [`std::lexicographical_compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare):

```
struct AsnObjectIdentifierComparator
{
    bool operator()(const AsnObjectIdentifier& lhs, const AsnObjectIdentifier& rhs) const
    {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.ids, lhs.ids + lhs.idLength,
                                            rhs.ids, rhs.ids + rhs.idLength);
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/4dy7I3)

Comment: What part of my code disrespected the strict weak ordering?

Comment: @NavjotSingh I suspect that it is `if (smallerOidLen == left.idLength)`. You can read about requirements for it: [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).

Comment: @NavjotSingh: Already your first loop: `{1, 3, 4} < {1, 5, 2}` but also `{1, 5, 2} < {1, 3, 4}`.