# How does the comparator function work in Priority Queue C++ STL?

Tags: c++, stl, comparator, priority-queue

```
class Student
{
    public:
    string a;
    int age;
    Student(string a,int age)
    {
        this->a=a;
        this->age=age;
    }
};

bool operator<(const Student &a,const Student &b)
{
    return a.age<b.age;
}

int main()
{
    priority_queue<Student> pq;
    Student a("max",1);
    Student b("john",1);
    pq.push(a);
    pq.push(b);
    cout << pq.top().a << " " << pq.top().age << endl;
    pq.pop();
    cout << pq.top().a << " " << pq.top().age << endl;
    pq.pop();
}
```

The output is-
max 1
john 1

On changing the comparator function

```
bool operator<(const Student &a,const Student &b)
{
    return a.age<=b.age;
}
```

The output is->
john 1

max 1

Can somebody please explain how does the comparator function change in case of < and <=?

Comment: A *Compare* type providing a **strict** weak ordering. `<=` does not meet this requirement. Thus you get undefined behavior, and you get your question illegal.

Comment: @jamesgem Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842749/stdsort-comparing-elements-to-null/21843204#21843204) explain a little better?

Comment: What is a strict weak ordering?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It does but what should I do if I want the order to change. Should I use <=?

Comment: @jamesgem -- Then use a greater-than only comparison, i.e. `>`.  And never use `<=`  or `>=` to determine if one item goes before the other.  If you read the answer given, you see why it doesn't work, since it is ambiguous for two equal items.  Strict-weak-order only wants to know which item is placed before the other, and if you give conflicting answers to that question, then the program gets confused and you get weird errors.

Comment: Here's [some documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) for how a compare function is required to work. What trips up a lot of people is that you need to return `false` for equal objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code is as bellow(vs2019 test):

```
// FUNCTION TEMPLATE _Debug_lt_pred
template <class _Pr, class _Ty1, class _Ty2,
    enable_if_t<is_same_v<_Remove_cvref_t<_Ty1>, _Remove_cvref_t<_Ty2>>, int> = 0>
constexpr bool _Debug_lt_pred(_Pr&& _Pred, _Ty1&& _Left, _Ty2&& _Right) noexcept(
    noexcept(_Pred(_Left, _Right)) && noexcept(_Pred(_Right, _Left))) {
    // test if _Pred(_Left, _Right) and _Pred is strict weak ordering, when the arguments are the cv-same-type
    const auto _Result = static_cast<bool>(_Pred(_Left, _Right));
    if (_Result) {
        _STL_VERIFY(!_Pred(_Right, _Left), "invalid comparator");
    }

    return _Result;
}
```

you can see the ambiguous compare is invalid.